# Pretty print Python xml.dom.Element object

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml.dom.Element object and would like to convert it to a string containing XML. There doesn't seem to be a method for this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [toprettyxml](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toprettyxml) or [toxml](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toxml) method:

```
elt.toprettyxml(indent = '  ')
```

For example,

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
doc = minidom.Document()
foo = doc.createElement("foo")
doc.appendChild(foo)
print(foo.__class__)
# xml.dom.minidom.Element

print(foo.toprettyxml(indent = '  '))
# <foo/>
```